# Using the Facebook graph API how do I tell if a user is online or not?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Need to know if a Facebook user is online or not.  Can't find the graph api call for this?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use **[online_presence](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user)** via FQL

---

The user's Facebook Chat status. Returns a string, one of `active`, `idle`, `offline`, or error (when Facebook can't determine presence information on the server side). The query does not return the user's Facebook Chat status when that information is restricted for privacy reasons.

Comment: I asked for Graph, maybe I'll have to switch to FQL.

Comment: FQL provides for some advanced features not available in the Graph API. https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk & http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ for more details.

Comment: this is an existing application I need to add a feature too.  My night isn't going well.  ;)

Comment: Is there a Graph alternative now that FQL is not supported anymore?