# Server-side detection of Facebook Connect login status

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application (specifically ASP.NET MVC) that allows members to register using their Facebook accounts.  So I'm trying to keep the sessions in sync, and if Facebook users sign out of FB after being active on my site, I want them to know that they will need to sign back in prior to doing any FB-specific actions.  Likewise, if they sign in to FB after having been signed out of my site, I want the site to detect this and sign back in.

I know how to sign a user in and out of FB, and have this working.  What I don't have working, is how to detect the above.  It seems like FB.getLoginStatus would do the trick, but I need a server-side way to do this.  I've messed with graph.facebook.com/oauth, but I don't think this is meant for doing what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph api doesn't support login status.

[Using the Facebook graph API how do I tell if a user is online or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535589/using-the-facebook-graph-api-how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-online-or-not)

I'm confused.  If you can sign a user in or out why aren't you simply chaining calls and saying "log out of facebook, logout over here"?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Let's say I'm on my site, and logged into Facebook.  I switch to another window and log out of Facebook.  But my site thinks I'm still logged into Facebook until the client FB.init script runs, and then resets the cookie, thus logging out of my site.  But this is taking place one request too late.  On the first request after a change (log in or log out of FB), the cookie isn't updated until after the request is complete -- and I need it to update before the request is complete, so I can update the views.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use HTTP status codes to get that information, the technique is simple and is described very nicely here https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user to facebook once when they first hit your site then you can send them to FB to authenticate.  If they are not logged in then authentication will fail.

This should work even if you are persisting the session as it is forcing them to login on facebook before you will use the token that you have.