# Get login status of a user Facebook

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

How to get the login status of a user by using their `Unique ID`?

Using `getLoginStatus()` the status of user currently logged in to my app can be retrieved. But i would like to know how to get status of another user.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535589/using-the-facebook-graph-api-how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-online-or-not](This is similar to this question) The first answer is what you're looking for

Comment: @ShemsEddine using `GraphApi` is the standard, `Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API is the last version where FQL will be available` from **Facebook**